# PHP jQuery AJAX I'm not sure what to write in the title

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm getting a SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

I tried adding/removing the following line of code: dataType: 'json', dataType: 'text', dataType: 'html'

I'm still getting

xhr.status: 200

thrownError: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

This is my Jquery Ajax Code

```
         $("#prodlist").find("tr:gt(1)").remove();
          $.ajax({
              url : 'ajax-product-search.php',
              type : 'POST',
              data :  { 'brID':brID, 'brType':brType },
              dataType: 'json',            
              success : function (data) {
                var objJSON, trHTML= '';
                $("#prodlist").find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
                objJSON = JSON.parse(data);
                $.each(objJSON, function (idx, item) {

                  trHTML += '<tr onclick="addMeToForm('+'\''+item.prID+'\''+','+'\''+item.prName+'\''+','+'\''+item.caName+'\''+','+'\''+item.prPriceL+'\''+','+'\''+item.prPriceVM+'\''+')">' +
                            '<td class="align-middle">' + item.prID + '</td>' +
                            '<td class="align-middle">' +  item.prName  + '</td>' + 
                            '<td class="align-middle">' + item.caName + '</td>' +
                            '<td class="text-right align-middle">₱ ' + formatCurrency(item.prPriceL) + '</td>' +
                            '<td class="text-right align-middle">₱ ' + formatCurrency(item.prPriceVM) + '</td>' +
                            '</tr>';
                });   
                $('#prodlist tbody').append(trHTML);
              },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
              console.log(xhr.status+ ':'+ thrownError);
            }            
          })
```

This is my PHP Code

```
  $products = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM products p LEFT JOIN category c ON p.caID=c.caID WHERE p.prActive=1 AND p.prSpecial=1;");
  $products->execute();    

  $response = array();
  while ($product = $products->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $response[] = array("prID"=>$product['prID'],"caName"=>$product["caName"],"prName"=>$product["prName"],"prPriceL"=>$product["prPriceL"],"prPriceVM"=>$product["prPriceVM"]);
  } 

  echo json_encode($response);
```

This is what the json_encode($response) looks like:

```
[{"prID":"HCP12154","caName":"Others","prName":"Bridel Uht Milk (advance Food)","prPriceL":"66","prPriceVM":"75"},{"prID":"HCP18044","caName":"Syrup","prName":"Vanilla 1.3l","prPriceL":"480","prPriceVM":"510"},{"prID":"HCP27718","caName":"Tea Leaves","prName":"Assam Tea 1.2kg","prPriceL":"750","prPriceVM":"800"},{"prID":"HCP37550","caName":"Tea Leaves","prName":"Jasmine Tea 1.2kg","prPriceL":"1000","prPriceVM":"1050"},{"prID":"HCP61746","caName":"Tea Leaves","prName":"Jasmine Tea 600g","prPriceL":"540","prPriceVM":"570"},{"prID":"HCP72044","caName":"Syrup","prName":"Hazelnut 1.3l","prPriceL":"580","prPriceVM":"610"},{"prID":"HCP89581","caName":"Tea Leaves","prName":"Assam Tea 600g","prPriceL":"420","prPriceVM":"450"},{"prID":"HCP97448","caName":"Syrup","prName":"Blueberry 2.50l","prPriceL":"550","prPriceVM":"580"}]
```

Comment: `dataType: 'json'` defines that returned data is already a json. So  - remove `objJSON = JSON.parse(data)` and iterate over `data`.

Comment: @u_mulder if I remove the JSON.parse I get this different error

http://prntscr.com/oo7yjx

Answer (score 1):

The response from your ajax call is already parsed as a JSON, because you specified it with the dataType property:

```
dataType: 'json'
```

So you dont need to use `JSON.parse()` on `data`. This is why you get an error.

```
$("#prodlist").find("tr:gt(1)").remove();
          $.ajax({
              url : 'ajax-product-search.php',
              type : 'POST',
              data :  { 'brID':brID, 'brType':brType },
              dataType: 'json',            
              success : function (data) {
                var objJSON, trHTML= '';
                $("#prodlist").find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
                objJSON = data;
                $.each(objJSON, function (idx, item) {

                  trHTML += '<tr onclick="addMeToForm('+'\''+item.prID+'\''+','+'\''+item.prName+'\''+','+'\''+item.caName+'\''+','+'\''+item.prPriceL+'\''+','+'\''+item.prPriceVM+'\''+')">' +
                            '<td class="align-middle">' + item.prID + '</td>' +
                            '<td class="align-middle">' +  item.prName  + '</td>' + 
                            '<td class="align-middle">' + item.caName + '</td>' +
                            '<td class="text-right align-middle">₱ ' + formatCurrency(item.prPriceL) + '</td>' +
                            '<td class="text-right align-middle">₱ ' + formatCurrency(item.prPriceVM) + '</td>' +
                            '</tr>';
                });   
                $('#prodlist tbody').append(trHTML);
              },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
              console.log(xhr.status+ ':'+ thrownError);
            }            
          })
```

Comment: i see. you have a php notice. Put this at the top of your php: error_reporting(0);

Comment: Of course it may be a good idea to check what the notice says, not just hide it... If you remove dataType: 'json', and than output console.log(data) at the beginning of your success function, you should be able to see the complete notice message ?

Comment: found the problem. ajax-product-search.php needs a parameter but I used $_GET not $_REQUEST. i change it from $_GET to $_REQUEST php now returns the json and its working now. thank you @francios huppe.

Comment: Last thing, shouldn't you use $_POST instead of $_REQUEST ? Both will work but your ajax call type is POST, so the common practice is to use $_POST to retrieve parameters in php